# Custom JWT issuance using ASP Data Protection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I'd like my ASP application to be able to issue its own JWT tokens that authorize specific actions to otherwise-unauthenticated users.

An example might be, say, exposing an unauthenticated endpoint for creating an entity and an authenticated one for editing the entity. The creation endpoint returns a token, and that's enough to authenticate requests for the same client to edit that entity.

It's super easy to generate cryptographic strings in ASP Core using something like:

```
IDataProtector dataProtector = ...; // from DI

// Create
var token = dataProtector.Protect(createdEntityId.ToString());

...

// Validate
var editingEntityId = dataProtector.Unprotect(token);
```

But I need a similar pattern in a few places, and I'm using AAD authentication elsewhere in the app, so I was thinking it might be nice if the tokens I return can be in JWT form. It's not the biggest deal, but it could make debugging a bit easier (since the content doesn't really need to be protected anyway), and it's more consistent if everything is a JWT.

So, in essence, I'd like to be able to generate a signed JWT with arbitrary claims attached to it.

I've found plenty of great resources for doing that, but these are representative:

- [Some depend on ASP Identity and `UserManager<T>`, which I don't have since I'm not dealing with user accounts.](https://andrewlock.net/implementing-custom-token-providers-for-passwordless-authentication-in-asp-net-core-identity/)
- [Almost all depend on a manually-managed secret, stored in configuration (or Key Vault, or whatever).](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2021/06/02/net-5-create-and-validate-jwt-tokens-use-custom-jwt-middleware)

But I haven't found anything that uses ASP Core's built-in rotating key management (`IKeyManager`, `IDataProtector`, etc.) to do it. It seems like that's great infrastructure for doing the core task necessary of a `SecurityKey`, but I've yet to find a way to utilize it.

It's straightforward enough to take an arbitrary piece of (even hard-coded) data, protect it using `IDataProtector`, and then pass it into a `SymmetricSecurityKey` as the secret, but then when I validate the token, if the `IDataProtector` key has been rotated, I'm not finding any way to validate it.

This seems like something that should be pretty common, and even part of some official framework to support Identity, but after much chatting with Bing AI and reading blogs, I've yet to find anything that points me to anything that'll do it.

The best I can come up with is to use `IKeyManager.GetAllKeys()` to encrypt a static byte array, then use those encrypted results as keys to build `SymmetricSecurityKey` instances which can then be used to sign and validate JWTs. But that's silly enough that I haven't bothered to even test if it'll work.

Comment: If you want a JWT then use ASP.NET Core's own JWT libraries: if you try to roll-your own then you'll likely end-up with a security disaster on your hands: ["never roll your own crypto"](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own) - also the `DataProtection` API in ASP.NET Core is meant for infrastructure use, not application use. Furthermore, JWTs are signed, not encrypted - whereas `DataProtection` is primarily all about encrypting data for first-party use.

Comment: @Dai Yeah, that's what I'm asking--how can I do this with built-in JWT libraries? Everything I've found around those depends on `UserManager<T>` which isn't relevant to my use-case. And yes, as I mention in my question, having a signed token--not an encrypted one--would be better for me, since I don't need the data encrypted and it would be more convenient.